# spinner in android

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

Hi I need to develop a spinner example in android. Here I have used below code:

```
 public class InsertionExample extends Activity {
 private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8089/XcartLogin/services/update?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/insertData";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "insertData";
Button btninsert;
String selectedItem;

static final String KEY_NAME = "orderid";
static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.change_status);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_insert1);
    btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent in = getIntent();
             String orderid = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);
             String status = in.getStringExtra(KEY_STATUS);
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
            unameProp.setName("Status");//Define the variable name in the web service method
            unameProp.setValue(selectedItem);//Define value for fname variable
            unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable

            request.addProperty(unameProp);
            PropertyInfo idProp =new PropertyInfo();
            idProp.setName("Orderid");//Define the variable name in the web service method
            idProp.setValue(orderid);//Define value for fname variable
            idProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
            request.addProperty(idProp);



              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

              try{
               androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

                 TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                  result.setText(response.toString());
             }
           catch(Exception e){

           }
              }
    });

    //attach the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    //Dynamically generate a spinner data 
    createSpinnerDropDown();

}

//Add animals into spinner dynamically
private void createSpinnerDropDown() {

    //get reference to the spinner from the XML layout
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    //Array list of animals to display in the spinner
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Intent in = getIntent();

    String status = in.getStringExtra(KEY_STATUS);
    list.add(status);
    list.add("Q");
    list.add("P");
    list.add("F");
    list.add("I");
    list.add("C");

    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    //set the view for the Drop down list
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //set the ArrayAdapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //attach the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

}

   public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

         selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

       }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Here the following `List` is added on spinner box:

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Intent in = getIntent();

    String status = in.getStringExtra(KEY_STATUS);
    list.add(status);
    list.add("Q");
    list.add("P");
    list.add("F");
    list.add("I");
    list.add("C");
```

Here the status is getting from previous activity value.other list is default Q,P,F,I and C.because the first list is displayed previous status only. So only I have to added status first here.

Now my problem is,

Now  my previous status is C means my spinner box have to displayed following format:

[image]

Here the first and last values are displayed C only. So the C value is available twice on my spinner box.
This is my problem. Here I want to **add the previous status first and also same time the previous status is not added another place**. How can I develop here. Please give me some solutions. For e.g;

If my previous status is P, then the first value displayed is P and also shows Q,P,F,I,C. So here P is displayed 2 times. So how can I resolve this error.

**EDIT:**

```
list.add(status);
    list.add("Q");
    list.add("P");
    list.add("F");
    list.add("I");
    list.add("C");
    for(i=0;i<list.length();i++){
        if(list.get(i).equals(status)) {
                list.remove(list.get(i));
        }
   }
```

Here I get the below error:
**The method length() is undefined for the type 
 List**

How can I resolve this error. Please help me

Comment: Check if your list contains status. If not add it, if yes just don't add it. Eventually if list contains status, check it's position on the list, then remove it from list, and add status.

Comment: i couldn't understand.please explain detailly

Comment: please read my edited question and give me solution for this

Comment: Put int position = -1; before for. Then in if replace youre list.remove... with position = i; and add break; . Then after for add
if(position>0) list.removeAt(position);

Comment: List in java doesn't have length(), tables have length. List has size(). Read Java and Android references.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18051/discussion-between-user1676640-and-agata-sworowska)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list.add(status);
list.add("Q");
list.add("P");
list.add("F");
list.add("I");
list.add("C");
int position = -1;
    for(i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        if(list.get(i).equals(status)) {
                position = i;
        }
   }
if(position>0)
   list.removeAt(position);
```

This if`if(position>0)
       list.removeAt(position);`
grants that if status is in your list, it will not be removed. It will stille be at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

use this condition after added list:

```
for(i=1;i<list.size();i++){
        if(list.get(i).equals(status)) {

                list.remove(i);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Don't ever remove items from list you are iterating through.

Comment: ya now i have problem here.i have used above code means my previous status is not displayed first on my spinner box.always siaplyed Q only..how can i resolve dis error.please help me

Comment: ya now i have problem here.i have used above code means my previous status is not displayed first on my spinner box.always first displayed Q only..but remove the previous status here.here i wish to need the o/p is my previous status is displayed first on my spinner box.same time that status is not displayed again on my spinner box,how can i resolve dis error.please help me