# android | create a dialog spinner from menu button pressed

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-menu

I want to create a language selector for my app. I created a button in the menu layout and I want a spinner to open when one of option menu is clicked . I'm a beginner so I'd love if you could explain your answers.

Comment: Android has a guide on Spinners: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spinner in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892782/spinner-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to create an xml layout where your spinner element will be placed

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:padding="10dip"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">



<!-- Spinner Element -->
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="Select Language"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

then i your activity where you would like to show the snipper you should implement OnItemSelectedListener interface for handling the selections of the spinner

```
public class SnipperActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //here you get the reference to the spinner element declared in your xml layout
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


  //set the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

 //here you create an arraylist for the items to be displayed in your spinner element
  List<String> languages = new ArrayList<String>();
    languages.add("English");
    languages.add("Greek");
  }

//define an adapter for the spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages);


 //set the style of the snipper, in this case a listview with a radio button
```

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_it em);

```
 //attach the adapter to your spinner element
  spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}
```

to handle spinner elements selection you have to ovveride the following method inside SnipperActivity class

```
 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String language = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

  //show a spinner item
  Log.e("TAG", "Spinner item selected " + language);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article on creating custom dialogs:
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

IMHO spinners are not very flexible. I'd use a listview in my dialog if I were you, but that choice is yours :)